MudBlazor d-flex column values
I am attempting to use variables in classes and column widths in a MudItem.
The source is a database record. The objective is to make the page dynamic, sourced from the database. The following line requires the "mColumns" to be an integer, but is originally a string. Is there a way I can convert mColumns to a string in this mark-up?
<MudItem id="@MyQuestion.Key" xs="12" sm="@mColumns" class="@MyQuestion.ControlCss" style="@MyQuestion.Style"> <label>@MyQuestion.Value</label> </MudItem> 
I tried converting mColumns to an integer and it worked, but I am ultimately hoping to use the source string.
I also tried using "MudElement" instead which allowed the use of the string.  Is there an advantage to using "MudItem" over "MudElement"?

I have learned that MudElement does not respond well to d-flex. What I am really looking for is a way to convert the variable in line in the razor page.  Something like "#mColumns"  which would theoretically convert the variable to an integer.

You can wrap the code in an @() to evaluate inline code.
So to convert a string to int inline you can use xs="@(int.Parse(numberStr))".
You can also omit the brackets if you wish xs="@int.Parse(numberStr)".
Razor syntax Docs
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">xs=12</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="@(int.Parse(numberStr))">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">xs=6</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="@number">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">xs=3</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code{
    string numberStr = "6";
    int number = 3;
}

Demo  MudBlazor Snippet

Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
